# How do I redirect a domain to a specific "landing page"?

Tags: redirect

My client has several parked domains. She wants those domains to point to specific pages in her main site. For example:

Let's pretend she has a page on her main site about bedroom redecorating. That page is located at www.mainsite.com/bedrooms/

And let's say she has a parked domain called www.999bedrooms.com/

She wants to redirect that domain to www.mainsite.com/bedrooms/

What's the best way to do this without being penalized by the search engines?

Also, keep in mind that www.mainsite.com/bedrooms is actually a WordPress page, so it's not an actual file on the server, per se.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to do this.  One way requires access to some sort of configuration on the server, and the other doesn't.  I don't know if you're using the Apache web server, but if you are, you would add `mod_alias` to your configuration and restart Apache:

```
a2enmod alias
apache2ctl graceful
```

Then add this to the VirtualHost section for 999bedrooms.com:

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.mainsite.com/bedrooms
```

Then you should be done.

The other way is in an HTML file that you put at http://999bedrooms.com/index.html, put a line like this within the HEAD section:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://www.mainsite.com/bedrooms">
```

This is one of those "Please wait while we redirect you to our main page" sorts of redirections that you see sometimes.  Not as nice as the server-based ones, but easier to do.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Well there are a couple way.  Most likely your web host supports the redirection for you using a 301 Redirect HTTP response.  Check out your web host and see if they offer a directory redirection (I know that fastdomain which is my hosting provider does).

Alternatively, if you hosting provide supports PHP you can use the following and place it in a file called index.php in the top level of the domain you wish to redirect.

`<?php

header("Location: http://www.mainsite.com/bedrooms/"); 



exit;

?>`

Answer (score -3):

Simply add this line to your header.php file:

```
<script language="JavaScript">document.location.href = "http://www.mainsite.com/bedrooms";</script>
```