# Change route segment dynamically in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, globalization

I created 2 routes like this to perform the localize:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { language = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
               );

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default2", 
                "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}",
                new { language = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );
```

Now I got 2 problems:

1. The default `www.mydomainname.com` doesn't automatically add `en` to URL. Desire result: when I enter `www.mydomainame.com` it should automatically change to `www.mydomainname.com/en`.
2. When I change the culture. How can I replace the default `language segment's value` on the route by `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` of that culture?

Please advice

Comment: [This will help you][1]
You can use domain redirection logic.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238517/how-do-i-redirect-a-domain-to-a-specific-landing-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approximate annswer so I hope it gets you on the right track.

CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName is a non static field and will depend on the user, so you're going to have to use a redirect to achive this (it cant be set in the global.asax file).

One way to to this is when the user requests the domain name, use the normal default route to route them to the home controller

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TypicalDefault",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Within the home controller, redirect them to the proper route

```
 public ActionReult Index(){
    var routeDataDict = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
    routeDataDict.Add("language", CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
    Response.RedirectToRoute(routeDataDict);
 }
```