# Redirect Domain Name Dynamically With Name Servers

Tags: dns, hosting, redirect, web-hosting

I'm trying to redirect multiple domain names to their corresponding landing pages on my website using name servers, but don't know where to start.

Example:

I have two domain names 1)ABC.com 2)123.com.  I want to set the name servers of each domain to forward them to the landing page on my website, so ABC.com would redirect to MyWebsite.com/abc and 123.com would redirect to MyWebsite.com/123.

Any help as to where I could a general direction to make this happen?

Comment: Check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238517/how-do-i-redirect-a-domain-to-a-specific-landing-page

Comment: That shows how to do one name, but not multiple domains to multiple landing pages.

Answer (score 1):

DNS is solely responsible for the name 123.com to address 12.34.56.78 mapping. It has no concept of anything that happens beyond that. Via DNS you would need to point both names to the address of the web server.

Then on the web server, configure a site at abc.com and 123.com, with each site being redirected the appropriate place.

This way, the HTTP software will detect which domain name is requested and redirect it as required.

You basically need to follow the link shared in comments, but do that for each domain. - [How do I redirect a domain to a specific "landing page"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3238517/5255018)